# Why Arjun called as Parth, not the other sons of Kunthi aka Prutha?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

Kunthi has three sons and Arjun is the last one. Kunthi also called with name Prutha before marriage and his son Arjun got the Parth because of this. But why only Arjun go this name though Yudhistar and Bheem are also her sons?

Struggling to find the answer for many years...

Comment: He was written about the most among the brothers and it was all in verse. So different names with different phonetic shapes must have helped the poet write euphonic / scanning poetry.